# Odoo Module Development error: AssertionError: Element openerp has extra content: data

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-view

I am a newbie in developing Modules for Odoo. I started developing a demo module according to documentation. But its giving error. I will provide you all the files & codes here. someone please help ..

My **openerp**.py file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': "Daily Transaction Manager",

    'summary': """
        Used For Managing entrys of our daily transactions.""",

    'description': """
        Used For Managing entrys of our daily transactions
    """,

    'author': "Peniel Technology LLC",
    'website': "http://www.penieltech.com.com",

    # Categories can be used to filter modules in modules listing
    # Check https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/master/openerp/addons/base/module/module_data.xml
    # for the full list
    'category': 'manager',
    'version': '1.0',

    # any module necessary for this one to work correctly
    'depends': [],

    # always loaded
    'data': [
        # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'daily_transaction_view.xml',

    ],
    # only loaded in demonstration mode
    'demo': [],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install':False,
}
```

My **init**.py file :-

```
import daily_transaction
```

My daily_transaction.py File

```
from openerp import fields,osv


class daily_transaction(osv.osv):
    _name= "daily_transaction"
    _description= "Daily Transaction"

    _coloums = {
        'subject': fields.char('Subject',size=128,required=True),
        'date' : fields.date('Date',required=True),
        'note' : fields.text('Notes'),
        'amount' : fields.float('Amount',required=True),
        'type' : fields.selection([
            ('transport','Transport'),
            ('household','Household'),
            ('personal','Personal'),
            ], 'Type',required=True),

    }
```

My daily_transaction_view.xml is like:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
<!-- Action -->
<record id="action_daily_transaction" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Daily Transaction </field>
    <field name="res_model">daily.transaction</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="search_view_id" eval="False"/>
    <field name="context">{}</field>
    <field name="help">Create new daily trasaction</field>
</record>   

<!-- Menu Code here -->
 <menuitem name="Daily Transaction" id="base.daily_transaction_roof" sequence="60"/>

 <menuitem id="menu_daily_transaction_roof" name="Daily Transaction" parent="base.daily_transaction_roof" sequence="1"/>

 <menuitem action="action_daily_transaction" id="menu_action_daily_transaction" parent="menu_daily_transaction_roof" sequence="20"/>

 <!-- Tree--> 
<record id="view_daily_transaction_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">daily.transaction.tree</field>
    <field name="model">daily.transaction</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Daily Transaction">
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="date"/>
            <field name="type"/>
            <field name="amount"/>


        </tree> 

    </field>    



</record>

<!--Form -->

<record id="view_daily_transaction_form" module="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">daily.transaction.form.view</field>
    <field name="model">daily.transaction</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Daily Transaction" >
            <group>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="date"/>
                <field name="type"/>
                <field name="amount"/>
                <field name="note"/>

            </group>    

        </form> 

    </field>    


</record>   


    </data>

</openerp>
```

When I tried to install ,Iam getting the error:

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 643, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 680, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 316, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 309, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 959, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 509, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 896, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 884, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 459, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_install, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 533, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.new(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 386, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 338, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 237, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 156, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 98, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 851, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 925, in convert_xml_import
    relaxng.assert_(doc)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3373, in lxml.etree._Validator.assert_ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:166352)
AssertionError: Element openerp has extra content: data, line 3
```

Comment: try to delete the Version="9.0" on form view.

Btw, i recommend you to use Api 8 and not old api if you are doing a new module

Comment: same error....is this old code???

Comment: Yes, it is. Ok, try with good tabulation since record is in the same level as data please, and edit your question with new code btw

Comment: what should i do?? is their any error in code?

Comment: No, its just old (search for odoo new api/old api). The error is for another thing in your .xml file, so please try what i said before untill we fix it :)

Comment: I edited the code.... I  checked it but showing same error...

Comment: The tabulattion in the .xml file?

Comment: ya..I changed it,..but nothing works...........same old error..

Comment: ok, then go step by step, try commenting all your xml file and just put the menu items, if it works we add the views later

Comment: kk done it.. ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: daily_transaction.action_daily_transaction" while parsing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/daily_transaction/daily_transaction_view.xml:19, near
<menuitem action="action_daily_transaction" id="menu_action_daily_transaction" parent="menu_daily_transaction_roof" sequence="20"/>

Comment: delete the action in the menu or else uncomment the action section of your xml

Comment: I changed.. & its showing as installed.. But I cant find it in apps list or menus or anywhere...

Comment: delete the "base." in your first menu:

 <menuitem name="Daily Transaction" id="daily_transaction_roof" sequence="60"/>

aswell in the parent below.. you should see it as a new menu when you install it

Comment: but not showing.. do i have to reatstart or something??

Comment: Do this: Put the new module on addons folder, restart odoo, install the module and refresh the browser

Comment: done...it.. I dont know whats the problem is? its still not showing.......

Comment: if you have your xml file added in the "data" attr of the __ openerp __.py, and in your xml inside you have  <menuitem name="Daily Transaction" id="base.daily_transaction_roof" sequence="60"/> inside the openerp and data tags, you should have a new menu when installing the module, i dont know what of these steps you are missing

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error when using a wrong "value" attribute for field:

```
<field value="myvalue" name="myfield"/>
```

and I did fix it with:

```
<field name="myfield">myvalue</field>
```

Check that all your elements are properly closed.

It seems that the validation error message is not properly shown.

Comment: What @yucer answered worked for me, in Odoo v10 I was getting `Element odoo has extra content: template, line 3` and the problem was the parameter of a XML tag, in my case I had written `inherit` instead of `inherit_id`.

Answer (score 2):

there is a spelling mistake in .py file and form view  .....

```
_coloums --> _columns

.py file --> 

_columns = 
{ 'subject': fields.char('Subject',size=128,required=True),
    'date' : fields.date('Date',required=True),
    'note' : fields.text('Notes'),
    'amount' : fields.float('Amount',required=True),
    'type' : fields.selection([
        ('transport','Transport'),
        ('household','Household'),
        ('personal','Personal'),
        ], 'Type',required=True),
}

<!--Form -->

<record id="view_daily_transaction_form" **module**="ir.ui.view"> 
<record id="view_daily_transaction_form" **model**="ir.ui.view">
```

I hope this Answer is helpful for you.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In daily_transaction.py File,

```
_name= "daily_transaction"
```

It should be like ,

```
_name= "daily.transaction"
```

Comment: its giving new error like attribute char not found &  module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given) like that

Comment: finaly.. its installed & menu showed up... but creation & listing causes error

Answer (score 0):

If you change any code in .xml file , Save that file and you must restart the server and Upgrade your module so that your edited file is loaded again on the server.

You can upgrade your module by command line as below:

```
./odoo.py -d db_name -u module_name
```

Only after upgrading your module the changes will take place.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, the problem is caused by misspelling at somewhere, such as the attribute names in the XML tags or tag value is between opening and closing tags but not a field value. Anyway, check it carefully, the errors do not show exactly where the misspelling is.

Answer (score 0):

In your daily_transaction_view.xml line number 3 there is one `<data>` element.

Odoo is not expecting that in your XML. Remove and try to upgrade your module. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You made a spelling mistake in the XML file.

It should be `model` not `module`:

```
<record id="view_daily_transaction_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">daily.transaction.form.view</field>
    <field name="model">daily.transaction</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Daily Transaction" >
            <group>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="date"/>
                <field name="type"/>
                <field name="amount"/>
                <field name="note"/>
            </group>    
        </form> 
    </field>    
</record>
```